# Auth0 refresh token in React Native fails with 401

Tags: react-native, authentication, auth0, refresh-token

In my React Native app -- init app not Expo -- I'm trying to refresh the `access_token` but my `POST` call is failing with `401`. I'm testing this functionality so I make the `POST` call some 30 seconds after I login so not sure if this plays a role or not.

In my initial login, I do get a `refresh_token` along with a valid `access_token`. I then tell my app to wait 30 seconds and make a `POST` call that looks like this:

```
const url = 'https://mydomain.auth0.com/oauth/token';
const postOptions = {
   method: 'POST',
   url: url,
   headers: {
      "content-type": 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
   },
   form: {
      grant_type: 'refresh_token',
      client_id: 'MY_CLIENT_ID',
      refresh_token: 'REFRESH_TOKEN_RECEIVED_DURING_LOG_IN'
   }
};

fetch(url, postOptions)
   .then((response) => {
       debugger;
       // this is where I get response.status 401
   })
```

Any idea what the issue is here?

Also want to mention that under my application settings, `Refresh Token` is checked under "Grant Types" but refresh token rotation or expiration are NOT enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out and sharing it in case others need it in the future.

First, Auth0 documentation is misleading at best. They keep mentioning a regular `POST` call which doesn't work.

In my React Native app, I use their `react-native-auth0` library. This library does offer a `refreshToken()` method which is what I ended up using.

Before I share the code, here are a couple of really important points:

1. Be sure to include `offline_access` in the `scope` of your initial authentication call for the user. Without including `offline_access` in your `scope`, you won't get a `refresh_token`. Once you receive it along with your `access_token` and `id_token`, store it as you'll use it many times. This brings me to the second point.
2. Unless you set it otherwise, your `refresh_token` doesn't expire. Therefore, store it some place secure and NOT just in `AsyncStorage`. As mentioned above, unless, you set it otherwise or it gets revoked, your `refresh_token` doesn't expire and  you use it again and again.

With that said, here's the code. Please keep in mind that at start up, I initialize `auth0` as a global variable so that I can access it in different parts of my app.

Here's what my initialization looks like in `index.js`:

```
import Auth0 from 'react-native-auth0';

global.auth0 = new Auth0({
   domain: "MY_DOMAIN.auth0.com",
   clientId: "MY_CLIENT_ID",
});
```

And here's how I use the `refreshToken()` method:

```
// First, retrieve the refresh_token you stored somewhere secure after your initial authentication call for the user
global.auth0.auth.refreshToken({ refreshToken: 'MY_REFRESH_TOKEN' })
   .then(result => {
      // If you're doing it right, the result will include a new access_token
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to add the authorization header with your access_token:

```
const url = 'https://mydomain.auth0.com/oauth/token';
const postOptions = {
   method: 'POST',
   url: url,
   headers: {
      "content-type": 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      "Authorization" 'bearer '+access_token,
   },
   body: JSON.stringify({
      grant_type: 'refresh_token',
      client_id: 'MY_CLIENT_ID',
      refresh_token: 'REFRESH_TOKEN_RECEIVED_DURING_LOG_IN'
   });
};

fetch(url, postOptions)
   .then((response) => {
       debugger;
       // this is where I get response.status 401
   })
```

Comment: I thought about that too and tried it but still got the `401` response.